# The Magic Chocolate Bar illusion

Tags: geometry

[image: This GIF is]

How is this possible, technically? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Looks like a version of the missing square puzzle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liI7rm5o1Rc

Comment: This image is an illusion. Vsauce explained this image in the beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s86-Z-CbaHA&t=449s).

Comment: This is not really a version of the missing square puzzle.  In the missing square puzzle, the image is accurate, and lines that appear straight aren't actually stright.  In this, the image is just inaccurate (the sizes of the pieces change after they move).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the southwest corners of the two trapezoidal pieces, the larger piece (that starts on the left) has a bigger part of a chocolate square than the smaller piece.  However, when they swap places the smaller piece jumps into place, growing a bit as it arrives. The animation is fast and jerky, concealing the small error.

Comment: Modulo horizontal stretch, an animation that makes it clear exactly what's being done is shown in the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltqHJTY8Fhk